# variable initialization

Tags: java, variables, initialization

I am new to Java and I cant fix an error in a script method. It says "variables city and state might not have been initialized"

Here is how I declared the variable:

```
String city;
String state;
```

Here is where my errors are:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println ("Enter the city you grew up in: " + city);
city = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println ("Enter the state you live in: " + state);
state = scan.nextLine();
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6):

You're using `city` and `state` before you initialize them.  Change the order and remove them from the `println` statement.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println ("Enter the city you grew up in: "); 
city = scan.nextLine();  // <-- Initializes city.
System.out.println ("Enter the state you live in: ");
state = scan.nextLine();  // <-- Initializes state.
```

**Update**

```
System.out.println(state.toUpperCase() + city.toLowerCase() + state.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: How could I create and print a new string that consists of the state name (all in uppercase letters) 
followed by the city name (all in lowercase letters) followed again by the state name (uppercase)?

Comment: See the bit under "Update".  Note that this will work now, since we've initialized city and state before we try to print them out.

Answer (score 0):

String city = "";

String state = "";

or

String city = null;

String state = null;

Use the above declaration, this will solve your error